# Mathematical statistical qm book-recommendation

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, textbook-recommendation, quantum-mechanics, statistical-physics

I feel that there are quite a few good and rigorous books on the mathematical foundations of quantum mechanics, but I am currently looking for a book that covers mathematical statistical quantum mechanics rigorously?

Is there any book on the market that you can recommend? Sometimes, I feel it is nice to have a rigorous book at hand when I am doing physics, which is the main reason why I would like to have such a book.

I especially like books that use quite some functional analysis.

Comment: **Quantum Physics: A Functional Integral Point of View** by Glimm and Jaffe (they're theoretical physicists). That's the closest I can think of, which should suffice since it is rigorous, but I find it hard to follow (they leave a lot up to the reader).

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=YuR4VQOQQUIC

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "mathematical statistical quantum mechanics", but I second the recommendation of Glimm and Jaffe (though it is really more about quantum field theory than quantum mechanics).  For a mathematical book on quantum mechanics, I like Quantum Theory for Mathematicians by Brian Hall, and also Quantum Mechanics: Foundations and Applications by Arno Bohm.

Comment: What are these "good and rigorous books on quantum mechanics"? I have had trouble finding any...

Comment: well, at least for my standard of rigorousness "Quantum Mechanics for Mathematicians" by Leon A. Takhtajan is okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two volumes by Bratteli and Robinson.
The book on lattice gases by Simon also has material on quantum statistical mechanics.

Answer (score 4):

D. Ruelle, Statistical mechanics. Rigorous results, Benjamin, NY 1969.